Does a superconductor with fewer defects flux pin more strongly?
In Jasper's answer its stated that the energy to move a flux-pinned superconductor goes into re-arranging the flux tubes that are passing through defects. In particular it's stated that it takes energy to move a flux tube away from a defect.
So now this motivates a question. Suppose we have 2 pinned superconductors different only in their number of defects. Is the superconductor with less defect density HARDER to move?
That is we have two superconductors both of the type 2 variety and both flux pinned in an identical configuration above an identical magnet with an identical NUMBER of flux tubes/amount of flux passing through them (visualized below). Is the configuration with FEWER defects going to take more energy to re-align?

This seems like a non intuitive result to me at least because the limit of this idea would suggest then an otherwise type-1 superconductor doped with a very small number of defects would be the "strongest" flux pinner possible (if you can align the defects and successfully get the object to pin above a magnet).
